# How can I use a group by after joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

Sql Query:

```
select Song.name as Song, Band.name as Band        
from Song join BandOnSong on Song.Id = BandOnSong.songId
join Band on BandOnSong.bandId = Band.Id;
```

Result:

```
Song              Band
Live Forever      Oasis
Penny Lane        The Beatles
Penny Lane        Test
Where is My Mind  Pixies
```

Expected Result:

```
Song              Band
Live Forever      Oasis
Penny Lane        The Beatles, Test
Where is My Mind  Pixies
```

How can I get the expected result? I tried using a group by on Song.name but I got an error doing that.

Comment: Can you tag your question with the database name you use, SQL Server ? MySQL ? The answer will depend of this tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Comment: I think you also need a field to base the order on. If you don't, you could also get "Test, The Beatles" as a result